# Is there an easy way to add an already existing CircuitLab schematic into the post?

Tags: support, circuitlab

I was looking at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/65640/1240) question which had a horrible image of the schematic. OP later added a CircuitLab schematic and it seemed to me that the best way to improve the question would be to embed it into the question and get rid of the image OP provided.

So I opened up the OP's circuit and the embedded editor and after looking for a while, I discovered that I couldn't find a way to get OP's circuit into a post. If I use Edit->Open in the embedded editor, I'd get moved to regular CircuitLab page with no option to insert the circuit. In the end, I just copied and pasted the circuit into the embedded editor, but this doesn't look like an elegant solution to me.

Is there a better way to embed an already existing CircuitLab schematic?

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand your question. In the example you gave, the OP posted a PNG of the schematic. Did you manually transcribe it into CircuitLab?

Comment: @weiy The original PNG was made from a CircuitLab schematic. OP later provided a link to that schematic in the comments as well as PDF export of that schematic. I wanted to add that schematic to the post, but it turned out to be impossible. Instead I had to copy all elements from that schematic and then paste them into a new schematic created using the embedded tool. Also some of the comments for that question were deleted including OP's comments where he links to CircuitLab and links to the PDF. This makes it hard to follow original conversation.